# choose serializer fields based on instance data

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to dynamically include/exclude particular fields on my ModelSerializer depending on the instance itself.  So, assume I have a hierarchical model which represents geography using self-joins:

```
class TreeModel():
    name = CharField()
    kind = CharField(choices=['country', 'state', 'city'])
    parent = ForeignKey(self, related_name='children')
```

Given that, say I wanted to hide the 'children' relationship links of an instance when the kind is 'state' but then show it when the kind was 'country'.  I tried fiddling with `get_fields` method but that didn't work.

I'm looking to do this because in my model some instances of the TreeModel class have thousands of children, but others have only a few.  I don't want to show the children for certain instance types because it is killing performance and I only need them for a subset.  Thnaks

Comment: you want to do this for retrieve request or list request?

Comment: If by "retrieve" you mean GET a single object (detail view v. list view) then yes, that's exactly what I mean.  However, given the serializer I use (JSONAPI) it also means that each individual object included in the list view would normally contain references to each field.  (this is not a nested serializer; I simply meant that if I request a list of "mixed types" it would still need to dynamically select the sub-fields based on each individual object type in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields) is what you're looking for.
DRF allows you to dynamically modify fields at the time of initialization of the serializer.

```
class TreeSerializer:
    def __init__(self , instance , *args , **kwargs ):
        super().__init__(instance , *args , **kwargs)
        if instance.kind == 'state':
            self.fields.pop('children')
        #Other Conditions
```

This example would hold because the first positional argument to a serializer is always the model instance.

There's another way to doing this without modifying the serializer : Using [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-init).
Here's my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43002832/5596800) demonstrating how to use them

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that isn't it (I should have mentioned that I read the documentation first.) The section to which you refer demonstrates how to specify the requested fields explicitly; I'm looking to have the list of fields be specified as a function of the instance itself.  If that answer showed how to access the instance within the class then yes, it would work.  But it doesn't show that.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm to going accept this because it works and answers the question I asked.  As it turns out, it doesn't solve the problem I have, but that's orthogonal to SO.

Answer (score 2):

```
class TreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        if instance.kind == 'state':
            self.fields.pop('children')
        return super().to_representation(instance)
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details and explaining to this?