# Django : ModelForm with conditions

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create a form variable. As default Player have the level 0 and he can just change is name. Later when he is level 1, he can change is name and is avatar. When he is level 3, he can change is name, is avatar and is job. Etc...

*Models.py:*

```
class Player(models.Model):
    level = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    avatar = models.URLField(default='http://default-picture.com/01.png')
    job =  models.TextField(null=True)
```

*Fomrs.py:*

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Player
    fields = ['name', 'avatar', 'job']
    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(),
        'avatar': forms.TextInput(),
        'job': forms.Textarea(),
    }
```

*Views.py:*

```
def game(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(Player, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Success')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=user)
    return render(request, "page/template.html",
            {'form': form})
```

*Template.html:*

```
{{ form }}
```

It's possible to add condition for the render of the form before send it to the render engime ? Or I need to do it in my Template with conditions ?

I just when to allow the instanced object to have more or less positibilies in terms of one of these parameters (in the exemple is the level of the player).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can overwrite the form's `__init__` method to remove or disable fields conditionally:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.level < 3:
            self.fields['job'].disabled = True # still displays the field in the template
            # del self.fields['job'] # removes field from form and template
        if self.instance and self.instance.level < 1:
            self.fields['avatar'].disabled = True
```

Comment: When you say "_still displays the field in the template_" The field does not appear or if i edit my html code i can remove the disable attribut, enter a new value and post it ?

Comment: From the docs: "The disabled boolean argument, when set to True, disables a form field using the disabled HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

Comment: Yes Django ignore the field with disabled but if you generate a form with attribute `disable` and the user have a brain, he can remove `disable` in the html code and post the form. Django don't ignore the field because he don't a the attribute `disable` is not present when the server receive it.

Comment: `# del self.fields['job'] # removes field from form and template` Sorry it's exactly what i want you have write !

Comment: Just a quick note for anyone looping over self.fields use self.fields.copy() to avoid getting "dictionary changed size during iteration" error.

Answer (score 1):

[Django pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#pre-save) can be used to solve this.
Before saving the model, the `hook` on `pre_save` will be called. You can write conditions in there to check if the user is allowed to change the fields.

You'll also need to store a copy of the model to compare the state in `pre_save`, it can be done through [post_init](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-init) hook.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver , Signal
from django.db.models.signals import post_init , pre_save

@receiver(pre_init , sender = Player)
def cache(sender , instance , **kwargs):
    instance.__original_name = instance.name
    instance.__original_avatar = instance.avatar
    instance.__original_job = instance.job
@receiver(pre_save , sender= Player)
def check_update(sender , instance , **kwargs):
    if instance.level == 1:
        #Revert changes to avatar and job, and keep changes in the name
    if instance.level == 2:
        #Revert changes to job , and keep changes in the name and avatar
    if instance.level == 3:
        #Keep all changes
```

This way you can keep track of all the updating fields.

Comment: I see signal is a solution what is the difference between signal and work in model `__init__` ? and this part of code is write in the views.py ?

Comment: In my opinion it is a much elegant solution because it keeps the management code separate from Model definition. Not only does it make your code more readable and self evident, but Its also easy to keep track of all the hooks this way when you have a lot of manipulation going around.

Comment: Your solution is very interessant, because i think signals are good a solution and with this, i don't just add a an attribute in the html like 'readonly' or 'disabled'. i will Try it, thank.

Comment: I prefer to write it at the bottom of `models.py` if their are a few models. Otherwise i prefer to write them in a separate file.

Comment: Ho well signal is write in the `models.py` i was not sur. I will go to learn the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this customizing your form in its init method

To the situations described Before, you can do some as:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ['name', 'avatar', 'job']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(),
            'avatar': forms.TextInput(),
            'job': forms.Textarea(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # checking if an instance exist
        if self.instance.id:
            # then at this point you can set as read only the fields about each case

            if self.instance.level < 1:
                self.fields["avatar"].widget.attrs["readonly"] = True
                self.fields["job"].widget.attrs["readonly"] = True
            elif self.instance.level >= 1 and self.instance.level < 3:
                self.fields["job"].widget.attrs["readonly"] = True
```

Comment: Thank for this answer but it's just write an attribute html : 'readonly' is not safe. If my user have a brain and edit the html, he can edit the value and post the form this it. But you solve an other of my problem. Thank.